# How to properly serve a loading page while server processes the request

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a web application that sometimes gets a bit heavy and takes a little while to load.

I would like to serve a loading page while the page that the user accessed is loaded on the server. Now, because this is not ajax, or a response to an event, I'm not really sure how to proceed here.

I came up with a rather ugly alternative that works like this:

1: user accesses `www.myapp.com/heavypage`.

2: if request comes from `myapp.com/loading`, then serve the `myapp.com/heavypage`.
   else, if request comes from anywhere else, rediret to `myapp.com/loading`.
   The page `myapp.com/loading` is basically a blue screen with a loading gif that fires a redirect upon loaded: `onload="redirectToHeavyPage()"`.

3: while the server processes the redirect (which takes time), the user is
seeing a pretty loading page.

[image: flow]

This way, I was able to show some information to the user while the `heavypage` action is processed on the server.

It works, but I feel like it is a totally wrong way of doing this, even though it works exactly I expected, mainly on slow connections (like gprs). Keep in mind that I can't put the loading gif anywhere on the `heavypage` because it will only be served when the server is done processing everything.

What would be the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

While your scheme works, a cleaner way to approach this is the following:

1. When the browser requests `/heavypage` only the HTML shell with a loading animation that does not require any processing or database queries is returned to the client. Preferably this step is be skipped completely by caching the HTML in the browser, a CDN or a reverser-proxy cache.
2. In the HTML, asynchronously load the expensive HTML via JavaScript. You do not need to wait for the `onload` event but can trigger this directly through an inline script tag.
3. In the response callback render the received inner HTML to the target element, e.g. the `body`.

This scheme works irrespective of whether you are using a single-page application framework like React or Angular or classic server-side rendering. The only difference is if 2. ships an HTML snippet or some JSON that is rendered client-side.

If you are using HTTP/2, there is another slightly more efficient solution to this using server push. When 1. is received on the server (or the CDN) the computationally expensive data can be shipped without waiting for the client request using the new push functionality. This is however only necessary, if the round-trip latency is slower than the time your `/heavypage` takes to render.